# 'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable'

Tags: python, playsound, python-playsound

'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable' while running simple playsound error in python 3.11.4 version

I tried everything according to different suggestions like
~ installed lower version of playsound i.e 1.2.2 which didn't install in the first place.
~ changed .mp3 file to wav file
~ also tried wave module instead of playsound

expectation was to play a song simply

Comment: Are you doing something like `playsound('blah.mp3')`? If so, you have two choices: either `import playsound` then `playsound.playsound('blah.mp3')`, or otherwise `from playsound import playsound` then `playsound('blah.mp3')`. Avoid mixing the two styles.

Answer (score 1):

without a sample of your code it's going to be difficult to help.

generally speaking a `'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable'` means you are trying to call a module like a function. Maybe you are calling the function without parentheses?